# How to set new state when window resize?

Tags: flutter

How to set new state when window resize ?
I tried this. I really need to change state.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraint) {
        setState(() {
          if (constraint.width > 500) {
            _calendarType = CalendarType.WEEK_MODE;
          } else {
            _calendarType = CalendarType.DAY_MODE;
          }
        });
        
        return Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            child: ...;
      },
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about you do this

```dart
...
if (constraint.width > 500) {
    _calendarType = CalendarType.WEEK_MODE;
} else {
    _calendarType = CalendarType.DAY_MODE;
}
...
```

Comment: I'm calling setState in build method. Are there any side effects?

Comment: Just updated the code, calling setState in build method has side effects. just make sure you are using a statefullwidget

Comment: You can also achieve the above by using a stateless widget alongside a Bloc which updates the state upon windows resize

Comment: Widget is statefull. If build method runs when setState is called, won't it be an endless loop?

Comment: Calling setState within the build method will try to rebuild the widget tree before the widgets gets built so you  need to try not to use setState there. Have you tried it like my example above?

Comment: The best way to get what you are trying to achieve is to use Bloc. I prefer flutter_bloc by felangel or you can try the provider package.